# how to sort integer and string in gridcontrol C#? this is my code :

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, gridcontrol, gridview-sorting

this is the class:

```
public static List<MasterReject> GetData()
{
var context = new FingerScanContext();
return (from a in context.MasterRejects
select a).ToList();
}
```

this is how i called the grid view:

```
 InitializeComponent();
 List<MasterReject> mrj = new List<MasterReject>();
 gridView2.OptionsBehavior.Editable = false;
 mrj = MasterReject.GetData();
 gridView.DataSource = mrj;
 searchLookItem.Properties.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
 searchLookItem.Properties.ValueMember = "ItemID";
```

Comment: You want to sort GridView Page?

Comment: i wish i can show you the screenshots but since im new i cant.. i only can post the code.. so there is a column named "Char"
A11
A1
A2

but my gridview (after being sorted) become :
A1
A11
A2

but i want to be sorted like this :
A1
A2
A11

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need natural sorting [Here is the link to how to do that](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question then you could just simply do this:

```
public static List<MasterReject> GetDatas()
{
    var context = new FingerScanContext();
    // assuming that Id is the primary key and you want to sort on that
    return context.MasterRejects.OrderBy(m=> m.Id).ToList();
}
```

Comment: still showing the same results..
 
i wish i can show you the screenshots but since im new i cant.. i only can post the code.. so there is a column named "Char" A11 A1 A2 but my gridview (after being sorted) become : A1 A11 A2 but i want to be sorted like this : A1 A2 A11

Comment: You want to sort the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static List<MasterReject> GetDatas()
{
    var context = new FingerScanContext();

    return context.MasterRejects.OrderBy(m=>Regex.Split(m.Replace("
    ", ""), "([0-9]+)")
   ).ToList();
}
```